# Sequence of Preimages goes to infinity for bounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis

*Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and let $T:X\to Y$ be a bounded linear operator such that $T(X)$ is dense in $Y$ but not equal to $Y$. Show that there exists some $y\in Y$ such that each sequence $(x_k)\subset X$ with $Tx_k\to y$ has the property that $||x_k||\to\infty$.*

**Example:** Let $X=Y=\ell^2$ and define $T(x_k):=(x_k/2^k)$. Then the set $F:=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_m,0,0,0,\ldots)\ |\ m\in\mathbb N\}$ of finite sequences belongs to $T(X)$ and is dense in $\ell^2$, so $T(X)$ is dense as well. But $(x_k)=(1/k)_k\in\ell^2$ does not have a preimage.

This is what I did so far: Since $T(X)$ is dense, we find for each $y\in Y$ a sequence $(x_k)\subset X$ such that $Tx_k\to y$. Since $T$ is bounded there is some $c>0$ such that $c||Tx_k||\leq ||x_k||$. From this it follows that
$$
\liminf_{k\to\infty}||x_k||\geq c||y||,
$$
which is not so bad. However, I haven't used the fact that $T$ is not surjective. I know that this implies that $T$ cannot be open, but I don't know yet how to work this in. I also have the feeling that the assertion is only true for some $y\in Y\backslash T(X)$.

**Since this is homework, please do not provide a full solution.** Light hints, however, are highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: By the way, it seems obvious that for some $y$, when $Tx_k \to y$, we don't have $x_k \to x$. Otherwise you'd have $Tx = y$ and $T(X) = Y$, contrary to the given conditions.

Comment: Exactly, so if $y\notin T(X)$, then its corresponding $x_k$ does not have a convergent subsequence. But this does not necessarily imply that $||x_k||\to\infty$...

Comment: Can you give an example of $X, Y, T$ ?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that a "constructive" (not in the technical sense) existence proof would at least be very difficult. So I suggest proving it by contradiction.

Suppose there didn't exist a $y\in Y$ with the given property. So for every $y\in Y$ there exists a sequence $(x_k)$ in $X$ with $Tx_k \to y$ and $\liminf \lVert x_k\rVert < +\infty$.

Then look at the open mapping theorem to conclude that $T$ would then be surjective. Depending on the version of the open mapping theorem, it may suffice to look at the statement, or one may need to look at the proof.

Comment: And if, by the time the homework is due, nobody has posted a full answer (and you don't want to write one yourself), you can ping me and I could write one.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Thank you. Your hint tells me the way to go. I will think about it and come back here later. Thank you again.

Comment: If it turns out you need a further nudge, feel free to ask.

Comment: Hm ok, our version of the open mapping theorem states that in my case $T$ being open and $T$ being surjective is equivalent (since both $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces). So assuming that for each $y\in Y$ there exists a bounded sequence $(x_k)$ such that $Tx_k\to y$, do I then have to prove that $T$ is open in order to get (by the open mapping theorem) that $T$ is surjective, which would lead to a contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $T$ is not bounded below. Then there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $\|x_n\|\to\infty$ and $\|T_n x_n\|\to 0$.  Considering $y=0$, we are done for that case.

We are left considering the case where $T$ is bounded below. But this case implies that the range of $T$ is closed, so the hypothesis doesn't hold and we are done.